# Setting up a systemd service to loop videos using VLC on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, vlc

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 that I'm using inside a display case to play some mp4 videos on loop. While normally I might simply open VLC using the desktop GUI, load them, hit play and maximize to fullscreen, I want this to be a bit more robust and capable of restarting itself. Also, I will note, for an undiagnosed reason, the above has resulted in video stoppage when I tried it.

What I've tried is to follow these instructions, but I would really appreciate some help to troubleshoot where I may be going wrong: https://gist.github.com/anthonyray/bb6fd7363cd99204330f17c54513f293

```
My videokiosk.service file looks like this:

    [Unit]
Description=videokiosk

[Service]
User=kioskman
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vlc -Rf pastels.mp4
WorkingDirectory=/home/sean/Videos
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Its status after loading and trying to run it was:

```
● videokiosk.service - videokiosk
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/videokiosk.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Fri 2022-07-22 10:47:52 EDT; 3min 56s ago
Process: 885 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vlc -Rf pastels.mp4 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 885 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 430ms

Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: videokiosk.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped videokiosk.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: videokiosk.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: videokiosk.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start videokiosk.
```

The journal looks like this:

```
-- Journal begins at Mon 2022-04-04 08:44:56 EDT. --
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi vlc[885]: > Shutting down.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi vlc[885]: [00486638] [cli] lua interface: Requested shutdown.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi vlc[885]: [afc0d578] cache_read stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi vlc[885]: [afc0e188] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: videokiosk.service: Succeeded.
░░ Subject: Unit succeeded
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit videokiosk.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: videokiosk.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit videokiosk.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped videokiosk.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit videokiosk.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit videokiosk.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1446 and the job result is done.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: videokiosk.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: videokiosk.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit videokiosk.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Jul 22 10:47:52 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start videokiosk.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit videokiosk.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit videokiosk.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1446 and the job result is failed.
```

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Comment: Surely you should use `WantedBy=graphical.target` if it is a video?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That makes sense. I've made the change and am getting mixed results. Initially, it seems to be working, but then if I recheck the status it says it exited again. And in the meantime, I haven't seen anything actually change or load on the desktop/screen.

Comment: Why do you have `User=kioskman` but Sean's working directory? Can `kioskman` *"see"* Sean's videos? And can `kioskman` access the GUI owned by `root`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell This was a key observation. I had become confused by the tutorial's suggestion not to use a/the root user and added one just for this purpose, but failed to grant permissions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what has worked: Changing the WantedBy field to graphical.target; granting permission to the directory holding the videos to the service user.

Thanks to @MarkSetchell for asking the right questions.